# Searching for %( in SQL

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, sql-like

I am searching for a string, '%(' in a column that contains various text.
This string can come anywhere within the text, so I tried to use LIKE clause in searching for string.

> where COLUMN LIKE '%(%'

However, this treats the % as a wildcard and searches every ( in the text.

To escape, I tried to use ESCAPE keyword

> where COLUMN LIKE '%(%' ESCAPE '%'

But this resulted in an error:

> Selection error involving field *N.

Please let me know if the string can be found.
Some of the strings involved are : `"%FOUND(....", or "...%SUBST(....", or even "...(%ABS(..."`

I am using DB2 on AS400.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WHERE column LIKE '%\%(%' ESCAPE '\'`

Comment: strangely, this does not works on my end, in my case, like '%\%(%' escape '\' returns no records

Comment: That is indeed strange, as this is definitely the correct syntax (you can use any character for '\', ie. `LIKE '%_%(%' ESCAPE '_'`)

Comment: Oh, finally it clicked: The string that I was searching had characters between % and ( so I had to insert another %. Hence my query became  LIKE '%/%%(%' escape '/'. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried following and it sorta works..

```
CREATE TABLE test(column1 varchar(500))
go
INSERT INTO test VALUES('42%344%lsdj%'),('hello%asgj%sdf%l8-')

SELECT * FROM test WHERE column1 LIKE '%344[%]lsd%'
```

Returns:

```
column1
--------------
42%344%lsdj%
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, but not as efficient as above,

```
WHERE INSTR(column,'%(') > 0
```

Comment: **@WarrenT** I might have missed out, OP has stated as `%(`, thanks for pointing out